# how to remove word that is split into characters from list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, nltk

I have a list of sentences, where some of them contain only one word but it is split into characters. How can I either merge the characters to make it one word or drop the whole row?

```
list = ['What a rollercoaster', 'y i k e s', 'I love democracy']
```

Comment: Do you want to delete words formatted like `y i k e s` from the list ?

Comment: @AlexandreMarcq ideally yes!

Comment: Is it only one char everytime ? Or can it be for example `yi k e s` ?

Comment: from what I have seen it is always with a space in between

Comment: what is the maximum & minimum length of a word? Do you know? If you do, i can help

Comment: unfortunately I dont know what the maximum length is but I'm happy to do a trial and error approach - the whole list is over 40k long....

Comment: Do you know how many 1 character long word there can be in an element? like "a"? as in "I use a laptop", where "a" is a word. so my question is, what is the maximum repitition of 1 character long word in an element? do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to avoid writing regular expressions as much as I can, but from what you told me, this one could work :

```
import re

a = ['What a rollercoaster', 'y i k e s', 'I love democracy']

regex = re.compile(r'^(\w ){2,}.')
result = list(filter(regex.search, a))
```

This captures strings having at least two groups of character and space, followed by anything else. This is assuming you wouldn't have a sentence beginning with something like `'a a foo'`.